# How to use rename both Parent and Child XML Nodes Using XLST?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to rename the following parent/child notes that sit a few levels down inside an XML document

```
<product-lineitem>
    <price-adjustments>
        <price-adjustment>
           ...
        </price-adjustment>
        <price-adjustment>
           ...
        </price-adjustment>
    </price-adjustments>
</product-lineitem>
```

into

```
<product-lineitem>
    <line-price-adjustments>
        <line-price-adjustment>
           ...
        </line-price-adjustment>
        <line-price-adjustment>
           ...
        </line-price-adjustment>
    </line-price-adjustments>
</product-lineitem>
```

I've figured out how to do this using XSLT but I think i'm duplicating my logic and probably misusing xslt, is it possible to do the above transformation in less than the following two templates below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="product-lineitem/price-adjustments">
            <line-price-adjustments><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></line-price-adjustments>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="product-lineitem/price-adjustments/price-adjustment">
            <line-price-adjustment><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />    </line-price-adjustment>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I think i'm creating xml-transform code smell as i'm still learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not creating a code-smell. The pattern you are using, with the identity template, and overriding templates for the elements you wish to change, is normally the way to go.

The one simplification you can make is that you don't actually need to specify the full path to the element you are matching. Just the element name will do

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="price-adjustments">
        <line-price-adjustments>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </line-price-adjustments>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="price-adjustment">
        <line-price-adjustment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </line-price-adjustment>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You would only need to specify a fuller path if you had a `price-adjustment` under a different element name, for example, that you didn't want to change.

You could also replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />` with just `<xsl:apply-templates />` if you were sure the element you are matching would never have attributes on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply looking to tighten your code, the following templates are also possible.

```
    <xsl:template match="price-adjustment | price-adjustments">
        <xsl:element name="line-{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

... or:

```
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'price-adjustment')]">
        <xsl:element name="line-{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

In the particular case of your sample input XML, shortening the code like this doesn't do much.  However, if you have a lot of elements that you'd like to rename in a similar fashion by simply prepending or appending another string, this could save you from having to write umpteen templates that all do essentially the same thing.

Comment: `<xsl:element name="{concat('line-', name())}">` can be simplified to `<xsl:element name="line-{name()}">`.